# Postgres - What is inserted when a delete executes?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I have been digging into Postgres' MVCC. I've watched videos regarding the behaviors of inserts, updates, and deletes. I keep seeing that a delete actually updates the `xmax` of the previous version and also possibly a commit flag and then inserts another record. I have yet to see any documentation or videos on what is actually inserted with a delete statement.

This seems very similar to Cassandra and its tombstone behavior, but have not been able to confirm. So my question is, what is actually inserted for a row when a delete occurs?

Comment: Take a look at [What’s in an xmax?](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/).

Answer (score 2):

A `DELETE` does not insert a new version of the affected row, it only fills in the `xmax` field of the row thereby marking it as non-existent for all later transactions. (see [this article](https://postgrespro.com/blog/pgsql/5967892) for more details)

So the answer to your question

> What is inserted when a DELETE executes?

is: Nothing is inserted. If you have any articles stating otherwise they are either wrong or unprecise.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meU2qKRzkCM&t=2502s Check out time around 16:40-16:45.

Comment: @JimWartnick They don't say a `DELETE` inserts something in this video. They say a `DELETE` updates the `xmax` (showing 10 rows in the video, one now having `520`) and as soon as the transaction is commited a `SELECT` doesn't show it anymore (now showing only 9 rows). However, the data is still there and can be found if you know how to look for it (using `pageinspect`).